# Can you explain this JavaScript function for me?

Tags: javascript

```
 function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countup(5)); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Could you guys please explain to me how this function works and when the variable "countArray" would push the elements to the array.

Comment: This is a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) function. `countup(0)` returns an empty array. `countup(1)` calls `countup(0)` to get the array, adds `1` to it and returns the array, etc. The number is added to the array here: `countArray.push(n);`.

Comment: Thanks, buddy! I think I got it now. It goes all the way down to the empty array and then starts adding the numbers to that array, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks a million, Felix! 

Hope I see your helpful comments on my upcoming questions.

Answer (score 2):

It is a recursive function that puts all numbers from `1` to `n` into an array. Lets look at the example with `n = 5`:

you enter the function and check if `n` is smaller than `1`, as this is not the case, you jump into the else statement, where the array `countArray` is initialized with the value of `countup(n - 1)`, therefore you start from the beginning of the function, but with `n = 4`.

This happens multiple times, until `n` is `0`, as in that case, the first if statement is true. By this exit condition, the function returns an empty array, which is assigned to the variable `countArray` in the function call in the previous 'layer' of recursion. After that, the variable `n` which equals `1` on that 'layer' is pushed into the array. These last steps also happen multiple times, as `countArray` is returned to the next call of the recursive function, in the same way as the empty array was returned.

After all recursive function calls were executed the resulting array `[1,2,3,4,5]` is returned

Answer (score 1):

This function will check first if the variable `n < 1`

If it is bigger it will run itself with `n-1`

If `n` is `0`, the function will return an empty Array and will go one "layer" back to the last function `countup(1)`
It will now add `n (1)` to the countArray and return this Array to the "last" function
Now the function `countup(2)`has recieved the number `1` in its `countArray` and it will return this. `[1, 2]`

It will repeate this process until the 'last' / 'first' function (`countup(5)`) is reached and it will return the `countArray` with all the numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

To understand recursions, sometimes you need to follow the execution of the code manually. Now the following line causes the recursive call and subtracts one from the number and then passes it to the recursive call.

```
const countArray = countup(n - 1);
```

Now imagine, if you passed 5 to the initial function call like so:

```
countup(5);
```

As 5 is not less than 1, the `else` block will be executed. The first line in the else block is the recursive call. So when your program encounters the recursive call, it stops execution of the current function until that recursive function call is concluded/returned. So the first recursive call will be:

```
const countArray = countup(4);
```

consequently, the same process will be repeated until `n` equals `0`. As 0 is smaller than 1, the if condition will evaluate to `true`. and it will return an `empty array`.

After the recursive call, it pushes the number to the array returned by recursive call. so the array at that point will contain `[0]` and then `[0, 1]` and it will keep adding numbers till the all recursive calls have been computed and then it will execute the rest of the intial function call.

Often times, recursion can be replaced by loops but thats not the case always. As a programmer one should be aware of this important topic.

Answer (score -2):

You call countup(2).
Since 2 is not less than 1, the function moves to the else branch.

It creates countArray and calls countup(1) recursively.

In the next call, countup(1) is also not less than 1, so it again moves to the else branch.

Another countArray is created, and countup(0) is called.

This time, countup(0) is less than 1, so it returns an empty array [].

The call to countup(0) resolves, and the array [1] is returned for countup(1).

The call to countup(1) resolves, and the array [1, 2] is returned for countup(2).

in the end the else branch will be executed many times inside the countArray variable and the final n will be pushed inside the countArray.